# How to Manage cron (ir.cron) when use Odoo Server with Load Balancing

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

Impacted versions:11.0

Steps to reproduce:
Install odoo in aws and add the load balancer over application end .When load in increased then new application server will be automatically launch with same configuration and now application server are two so that two cron job are running at a same time with different slave because all server embedded his scheduler job .

Current behavior: When use load balancer (hardware or software) with multiple Odoo Server, (1 master and multiple slave), there is a problem with scheduling (ir.cron), because all server embedded his scheduler job .

Expected behavior: How to run the cron job in case of load balancer.